# Visual Studio no template variables defined in type_traits

Tags: c++, type-traits, variable-templates

When I tried use `std::extent_v` template it was underscored with red and I got error "namespace std doesn't contain member extent_v" in IDE, but it compiles without an error (`<type_traits>` is of course included).

When I found its definition in `<type_traits>` it was disabled along with other variable templates definitions in conditional `#if _HAS_VARIABLE_TEMPLATES`. `_HAS_VARIABLE_TEMPLATES` was defined as 0 depending on `__EDG__` macro, that wasn't introduced in source code.

What it all means and how can I repair IDE?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Comment: Read the part about Variable Templates: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/11/compiler-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-2/

Comment: If intellisense and the compiler disagree, it's usually intellisense that is wrong.

Comment: IntelliSense uses the [EDG](http://www.edg.com/) compiler front-end. The compiler itself uses either MSC or Clang. The issues reported by IntelliSense are not authoritative.

Comment: Intellisense is very good, but it is not as mature or complete as cl (Visual Studio's compiler). It will some times fail to parse constructs that are in any way "unusual". There usually isn't much you can do other than file a bug report.